# Docker не монтирует volume внутрь контейнера

Tags: docker

Мне нужно собрать проект в докер-контейнер и запустить его. Собирается. Запускается. Но сам проект (каталог src со всем содержимым, а так же конфиг апача default.conf) в контейнере отсутствует. В чём може быть дело?

Структура проекта:

```
apache
  default.conf
php
  Dockerfile
src
  index.php
docker-compose.yml
.env
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    dadata:
        container_name: dadata
        build:
            context: ./php
        ports:
            - '80:80'
        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/www/DadataSocketServer
            - ./apache/default.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:8.0-apache

RUN apt update && apt install -y zlib1g-dev g++ libicu-dev zip libzip-dev zip libpq-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl opcache pdo pgsql pdo_pgsql \
    && pecl install apcu \
    && docker-php-ext-enable apcu \
    && docker-php-ext-configure zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip

WORKDIR /var/www/DadataSocketServer
```

**Собираю так:**

```
xxx@xxx:~/docker/dadata-websocket/php$ docker build -t dadata-img .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.584kB
Step 1/4 : FROM php:8.0-apache
 ---> 1a23db600d20
Step 2/4 : RUN apt update && apt install -y zlib1g-dev g++ libicu-dev zip libzip-dev zip libpq-dev     && docker-php-ext-install intl opcache pdo pgsql pdo_pgsql     && pecl install apcu     && docker-php-ext-enable apcu     && docker-php-ext-configure zip     && docker-php-ext-install zip
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2830245fa9f3
Step 3/4 : WORKDIR /var/www/DadataSocketServer
 ---> Running in 5ab7056aeef5
Removing intermediate container 5ab7056aeef5
 ---> a684a22b1958
Step 4/4 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Running in a43afd2bc42f
Removing intermediate container a43afd2bc42f
 ---> 2e63ba0d37e6
Successfully built 2e63ba0d37e6
Successfully tagged dadata-img:latest

xxx@xxx:~/docker/dadata-websocket/php$ docker run -p 80:80 --detach --name dadata-container dadata-img
4bcf7e0e49d796c6a53097648f13f97b2f1bf4e759373e5927d726d2b8d8d89c
```

Comment: Вас не смущает, что маппинг папок описан в докер компоуз, а билд и запуск - просто докер? Не пробовали `docker-compose up -d` или прописать мапинг через `docker run -v source_folder:container_folder`

Comment: Хм, файл docker-compose.yml обрабатывается только командой docker-compose? Не знал. Это мой второй контейнер, который собираю, поэтому сильно плаваю в теме. Выполнил docker-compose up -d --build и всё получилось. Спасибо!

Comment: Да, docker-compose - по сути - обертка для докера, которая позволяет работать с мультиобразами и набором дериктив (конфигов) из yaml файла. И хоть под копотом все равно он вызовет docker, он сделает это с определенным набором параметров (Это если упрощенно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к. у вас есть docker-compose.yml, то используйте `docker-compose up -d`